# Long way to catch up?

Tags: grammar

My friend and I watch the same TV show, but she's on 5th season and i'm on 2nd. so she tells me what's going to happen next, what do i say here "God, i got a long way to catch up " or what, to say that i want to catch up , or be in the  same season she is on. Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use "I *have* a long way to catch up" or at least "I *have got* a long way to catch up" instead of "I *got* a long way to catch up".

Recommended reading: [Is using "have" better than using "got" in the following sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9845/is-using-have-better-than-using-got-in-the-following-sentence)

Comment: Disagree.  "I got a long way to go" is common usage in spoken English, whereas the other more grammatically correct options are not as commonly spoken in casual conversation.

Comment: @andi [citation needed]

Comment: In fact, [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+got+a+long+way%2CI+have+a+long+way&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20got%20a%20long%20way%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20have%20a%20long%20way%3B%2Cc0) is a citation showing that "I have a long way" is used much more frequently than "I got a long way".

Comment: your citation refers to WRITTEN English, not spoken English.  I would agree that "I have a long way" is much more common in written English.

Comment: I think _I've got_ is more common in spoken English, although there are some dialects (e.g. Ebonics) where _I got_ is common.

Comment: @andi "I got..." and "I have..." semantically mean two different things, so they aren't interchangeable here. All I'm saying is that I've heard "I have a long way" much more often than "I got a long way". Written English backs up my claim, so I'd be curious if you can contribute some figures that back yours up. Let me guess... you're from the south? :p

Comment: I tend to use "I've got" most, when I personally speak.  But I hear "I got" most often from others.  And no, I am not from the south.  Kevin, can you describe the semantic difference between, say, "I got a headache" and "I have a headache" in spoken English?  How is that not interchangeable?

Comment: Got = obtained, have = posses. Saying "I got X" means "I obtained X" whereas "I have X" means "I posses X". So in your example, "I got a headache" implies that you recently noticed the headache, whereas "I have a headache" means that you might have had the headache for some time. This is also why "I have (possess) a long way to go" is more correct than "I got (obtained) a long way to go". This is all explained in the link I posted in my answer.